# AWS Quicksight - Display the username in the report

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-quicksight

I would like to know if in AWS Quicksight there is a way to display the username that is logged in within the report. I was able to put dates or some other filters, but still no username.

Something like this (This is Tableau):

[image]